# Javascript/Webpack pipelining in Rails 6. application.js syntax. putting js files in javascript/packs folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have one bootstrap template for doing a rails project. Before rails 6 it was easy to integrate a template with a project. Now in rails 6 webpack is included. Now i am not able to copy files to javascript/packs folder and call those .js files by application.js. While compiling the webpack, it is showing:

> ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'plugins/jquery/jquery.min' in
>   'app/javascript/packs' 
>   @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 25:0-36 <= this error

Comment: Hey, to render files from your packs directory use this in your template
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'file_name' %>

Comment: i am having more than 90 .js files. each one needs to render like this?

Comment: Nope you have to import them in your application.js or you can use require tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created src folder inside `app/javascript` folder and pasted all `.js` files into it. `application.js` also done by `require('src/file_name')`, and then I changed `webpacker.yml` `resolved_paths` to `resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/src']` . Now it is working fine.